# CakePHP - Infinite Loop in Login

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have two groups for users. When I login with an admin user, it works, but when I try to login with an user from the other group I get an infinite loop.
This is the code I'm using:

UsersController.php:

```
public function login() {
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
    $this->redirect('/pwds', null, false);
    }
else
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
            }
        }
}

public function logout() {
$this->Session->setFlash('Good-Bye');
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
//$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}
```

AppController.php:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent

$this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pwds', 'action' => 'index');
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem. NonAdmins users weren't allowed to do anything at all, not even login, so they were redirected to login view, creating an infinite loop.